# Meta does in fact have low quality questions

Tags: discussion, meta, psa

Basically anytime a meta question gets downvotes someone invariably shows up to tell the author things along the lines of, "Don't worry about the downvotes to your question" because "downvotes on meta are just disagreement" or "downvotes on meta don't affect your reputation". Now yes, voting on meta is a bit more complex than on more traditional sites, but I'd say quite a bit less than a lot of people seem to either think or convey to newer users.

Lots of posts on meta are just *bad posts*.  They're poorly researched, not clear, are not providing good proposals (i.e. not explaining why their proposal would be helpful), are not constructive in their tone, are simply discussing trivialities that no one cares about, etc.

It's both misleading and unhelpful to tell every single user posting a question proposing, "People should have to comment when they downvote" that all of the downvotes are just because people disagree.  Stating, or implying, that there aren't *major* problems with these types of questions is unhelpful as it prevents them from fixing those problems, or avoiding those issues in future questions.  Often people don't *explicitly* state that there are no other problems, but posting comments like, "Don't worry about the downvotes, they're just because of disagreement" is pretty strongly *implying* that the question is otherwise good, and regardless of what people posting those comments mean, many question authors *interpret* those comments as meaning the questions are otherwise good, and people just disagree.

Sure, lots of people *do* disagree with these perennial requests, but that doesn't change the fact that the question is comically poorly researched, virtually always not thought out, doesn't provide any new insight, often isn't constructive in tone, etc. Those types of questions merit (and often get) downvotes even when the community is in support of an underlying proposal (or when there isn't any proposal to agree or disagree with). And when there isn't an underlying proposal, either stated or implied, this just causes even more confusion.

Now sure, I'm not saying that everyone should be spending hours at night losing sleep over getting some downvotes on a meta post, but it *is* helpful to at least recognize when a question has problems beyond just whether any underlying proposals are a good idea. Yes, it's often *easier* to tell someone "people just disagree" than to go over more technical problems with a question.

This is mostly because people take it better to know that they "asked a good question"; we just don't like it, than to hear, "You didn't do a good job asking your question." It also means that the next time they go to ask a question they're not going to fix those problems. They're not going to spend more time looking for previous proposals on the topic, getting concrete evidence to support their proposal, trying to have a more neutral tone in their proposal, etc.

All that said, sometimes there are cases where you feel someone really did ask a great question, and you think they've done their research, asked a clear and well-formed question about something that's on topic and interesting, but that is proposing something that you think would be harmful if implemented, and choose to downvote as a result.

If you really think that that's what's happening (either because that's how you voted yourself, or because you really can't see any other problems with the post besides the underlying proposal) then by all means, mention that you think people might just disagree with the proposal. But honestly, I think those questions are rarer than a lot of people think.

If you don't want to walk someone through all of the technical problems with their question, that's fine (I often don't, it's a lot of work, and there's too many bad questions); just please don't post a comment telling the author (or implying) they asked a good question or that it doesn't have other problems unless you really believe that, and took the time to consider what other problems might be able to be fixed in it.

Comment: For the record, I've always despised people leaving "it's just disagreement" comments. I frequently delete them, and my hatred for seeing it correlates to [the tone in a previous rant about them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337520) that's swelled since I [first started speaking out against the idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146057) four years earlier.

Comment: Not to mention [misapplication (joking or not) of the "lost keys"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355553/so-what-is-the-purpose-of-downvoting-an-answer/355560#comment507189_355560).

Comment: @JoshCaswell For the record I think Tim's post is actually decent enough. My reading is that Tim isn't trying to say that votes should just generally be ignored whenever you want them to be.  But lots of people seem to say, or imply, as much when paraphrasing it, which I consider very problematic.  And I agree that when people are being sarcastic some users won't realize it and will take their jokes literally, to their detriment.

Comment: Definitely; it's misused/-construed, not inherently problematic.

Comment: @animuson I was going to suggest precisely that "previous rant" of yours as related reading.

Comment: So, what is *your* question?

Comment: @Jo. I'm not asking a question.  I'm proposing people act differently in how they provide feedback, via comments, on meta questions that are attracting downvotes.

Comment: @NicolBolas Usually you see it when a question becomes the "flavor of the month" and there's a new question asked about some topic every few days for weeks on end.  Even if lots of people agree, they start downvoting the duplicates for being duplicates.  The most prominent case I can think of (which, granted, is not at all recent) related to people constantly complaining about how large the close vote queue was and wanting changes made to make it smaller.  Lots were upvoted, but lots of ideas kept getting repeated shortly afterwards, and getting downvotes as a result.

Comment: Anyway, the point here is not that no one ever downvotes a post because they think the proposal being suggesting wouldn't be useful to implement, it's that lots of questions have other problems, and it's not helpful to tell everyone writing a proposal that is *both* poorly written *and* a bad idea, that it's only getting downvotes because it's a bad idea.  Seeing *really well written* proposals that are also just bad ideas is...rare.

Comment: @Servy I've actually been thinking of asking a question about this for a while, along the lines of changing the [Voting is different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) section's phrase "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself." I saw that in 2016 [you changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/250231/6) the "rather than" to "in addition to" in the tag description, and I think that was a good change and the help center should say the same.

Comment: ...okay, I admit I'm confused.  Meta has bad posts and has poor suggestions but I've always seen these things as distinct.  I'm not sure what you're getting at here.  I think you want us to be more specific with the guidance we provide others, but I'm not seeing any suggestions in this discussion to motivate that.

Comment: @Makoto When people post an idea that is *both* poorly asked and *also* something that lots of people think is a bad idea, it's very comment for people to comment either saying, or implying, that the question is a good question and that people *just* disagree with the idea proposed.  I find that to be a problem.  I would want them to make it clear that the question *both* has problems with *how* it's making the proposal, and also *what* it's proposing (when applicable).  What you'd specifically say would simply vary a lot from post to post, so I haven't given specific suggestions.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I follow now.  You're basically saying that one signal (e.g. the poor post) is being overridden by people saying that "oh, it's just disagreement".  I suppose then the follow-up question would be, why would it not be the case that those poor questions are closed as the stronger signal of quality?

Comment: @Makoto Often the questions don't get closed.  There's no close reason for, "You didn't provide any evidence to support your proposal." or "You didn't explain why this is a good idea."  I also see lots of comments from the OP like, "Oh, it's good to know that it's just disagreement," and things like that that.

Comment: @Servy from your main post, I have no idea whether you agree or disagree with your segment, *"People should have to comment when they downvote"*. Your third paragraph is one single sentence. Could you add a second to clarify, plz. :-) (You are a good writer, I'm a writer myself, but that part was unclear to me.)

Comment: @JesseSteele Better?

Comment: @Servy Honestly, that makes it worse because the paragraph about trippled in size, but still has not clear: *I want votes explained* or *I don't want votes explained, stop asking for it* type of statement. I see a lot of what you **don't** mean, just not anything about which side you're on with the topics you raise.

Comment: Side comment here about writing, you could be syndicated if you'd take five years, write daily, and give yourself a 200 word limit each time. That would make you awesome as a writer; it worked for me. Digression finished, but it is related.

Comment: _Meta does in fact have low quality questions_ QED. But: so what? Meta is just a log of quarrels, not an archive of knowledge, so the quality of questions is 100% meanigless. Your post, btw, is WAAAYYY to long.

Comment: @TaW Your perception that the post is way too long is much more telling of your attention span than it is of the post's actual length.

Comment: Potential close voters: there is no sensible justification whatsoever for closing this question. Please note this is a Meta [discussion].

Comment: @Servy I hope you don't mind the edit. Feel free to discard it

Comment: @duplode ah gotcha. Yeh, I don't understand the close votes either. That's meta

Comment: My reason was 'Unclear what you are asking', not 'Opinion based'.

Comment: @Servy I got you now. ;-)

Comment: We need more PSA posts like this. Maybe I should make a [psa] tag. Sometimes a moderator or Meta regular just needs to get on the soapbox and knock some sense into everybody. (I get the feeling @YvetteColomb will strongly agree with me on this.)

Comment: @BoltClock I strongly agree.  Care to make a tag?

Comment: downvotes on _this_ post mean just disagreement. It is correct to interpret my comment as meaning _this_ questions is otherwise good, and people just disagree :)

Comment: Similarly, upvotes on questions don't just mean agreement. Many people upvote a question because they think it's important.

Comment: @Gnat I disagree. There's already been someone complaining that the post is unclear, which would mean it's not useful and therefore downvotable for a reason other than disagreement, and someone else who has complained about the question's length. Trying to claim that "downvotes on *this* post mean just disagreement." is simply a (bad) attempt at mind reading. Certainly I cannot guarantee those two complainers downvoted for those reasons, but given that they commented those things, it quite short-sighted to claim that the downvotes just mean disagreement.

Comment: @DavyM your note kind of supports the point made by OP, that comments about meta downvotes meaning just disagreement are troublesome

Comment: @Gnat It doesn't "kind of suppor[t] the point made by the OP," it absolutely supports it. Comments like the one you made are a prime example of why such comments are "both misleading and unhelpful to tell" users that downvotes on their post are just because of disagreement.

Comment: @TaW I think a lot of that is precisely a consequence of the problem I've identified, and exactly what I want to change.  If people asked better meta questions those questions would be much more useful to other people (or the bad questions simply wouldn't be asked).  By not even so much as acknowledging that posts have more technical problems with them, people don't fix them, and those more technical problems often prevent those posts from having lasting value to other people.  You'll find many of the more well written meta posts *do* have lasting value, and get referenced for years to come.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm trying very hard to keep the question focused on having people acknowledge that many meta questions have quality problems, and keep discussion away from "disagreement" as much as possible.  There are lots of meta posts on how people do vote, or how they should vote, and how "disagreement" comes into play (many of which are reasonably well written and cover anything I have to say on the subject already).  I don't want this to be another one of them, hence the title.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I know the title is slightly hyperbolic, but I chose it rather specifically because I've seen some of the *worst asked* questions on here, that are just *terribly* constructed (core ideas aside) and I see people posting comments saying, "Don't worry about the downvotes, they're just disagreement".  I know most of the people saying those things realize that there is such a thing as a low quality question, but their actions convey the opposite to people not familiar with meta, given that [almost] no question is so bad on a technical level people will actually tell them to fix it.

Comment: Honestly Nicol Bolas' answer pretty much proves my point. Saying that we should never bother to tell anyone that their question has problems with how it's written, if it's proposing an idea people don't think is helpful, because it'd be downvoted anyway.  While it's not *technically* saying there's no such thing as a low quality question, refusing to ever acknowledge makes it seem that we think that way to people who aren't regulars.

Comment: It is so easy to fall into a pattern. I used to give a similar comment (but far less definitive) when someone would start to throw a fit over the downvotes their question would be receiving on meta. That tends to happen when a meta post is itself about receiving downvotes, or closure. Meta voting **is** different, it can throw people off. And before you know it you start to comment such things when you can smell the anger coming due to the context and tone of a question. And before you know it you start to post it whenever downvotes start to flood in. Bad. Wrong. Full stop.

Comment: @BoltClock: "*We need more PSA posts like this.*" I'm curious: who exactly would decide which "announcements" constitute a "public service"? That ultimately requires the post to be considered correct in some way, which means someone has to decide that it *is correct*. Who would that be?

Comment: @Servy: "*Saying that we should never bother to tell anyone that their question has problems with how it's written, if it's proposing an idea people don't think is helpful, because it'd be downvoted anyway.*" Here's the question: is it true? Because if that's true, if their question would be downvoted regardless of how good or bad it is, regardless of how well or poorly researched it is, simply because it is a thing that people don't want... why is it unreasonable to tell people that truth? Are you unwilling to take responsibility for the world your voting patterns have created?

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't think it matters whether it's true or not.  And neither I, nor anyone else, can ever know, or prove, whether it's true or not.  We can only ever guess at how people vote.  Even if you *did* get a mind reading device, and everyone actually voted the same way, so you could prove such a thing, it's unreasonable because *the quality of how a question is asked still matters*.  It makes the site better when people do their research, are clear, provide evidence to support their positions, etc.  Even if they're not doing it for the imaginary internet points, it's still worth doing.

Comment: @NicolBolas Also, I'm not "creating" any voting patterns other than my own, nor am I, or anyone, responsible for any votes other than their own.  Again, this is not a post about encouraging people to vote strictly on whether or not they think implementing a proposal is helpful, nor am I the "creator" of that idea.  You're free to use whatever criteria you want in determine whether a given post is "useful" on this site, and only you are responsible for the votes you cast as a result of whatever decision you come to.

Comment: @Servy: "*We can only ever guess at how people vote.*" Not in this case. Many such questions actually get answers, usually explaining in detail what the person did wrong in whatever it was they asked about. And those answers get upvoted, despite the downvoted question. I have 23 Reversal badges that are almost all of this sort, and I suspect most of the 77 you have are like this too. I don't need to "guess" to see the correlation there, especially when other Meta sites *don't work that way*. They will upvote posts and upvote answers that argue against the OP.

Comment: @Servy: "*Also, I'm not "creating" any voting patterns other than my own*" And yet you are. Voting is anonymous, but the *results* of voting is public. Thus, how someone sees a question get scored influences how they themselves will vote. If someone sees everyone downvoting a question that they disagree with, they *will* believe that's just how the system is supposed to work. That's how a culture propagates itself. Your voting does influence others.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, you *suspect* that's the reason *some* people are voting *some* of the time.  That doesn't change the fact that 1) it's 100% irrelevant to the point.  Even if you could prove that everyone always voted that way, my point still stands 2) Not everyone votes the same way.  Are you going to tell me that *you* always vote that way? 3) just because there's a correlation there that is consistent with your guess doesn't make it true.  Yes, there is some evidence suggesting this is the case.  But, once again, proving it is pointless because it doesn't *matter* if it's true or not.

Comment: @Servy: How can the truth not matter? If it's true, then you are telling people *not to tell the truth*.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not saying any such thing.  I'm saying you shouldn't tell people that they asked a well written question, or to mislead them into thinking they asked a well written question, when they didn't.  If you want to *also* say that people may be downvoting because they don't think the proposal is a good idea to implement, by all means, have at it.  **You** are the one encouraging people mislead others into incorrectly thinking a poorly asked question is well asked, because according to you it's okay to lie about that as it doesn't affect voting (in your opinion).

Comment: @Servy: "*You are the one encouraging people mislead others into incorrecting thinking a poorly asked question is well asked.*" That's only if we start from your presumption that telling people that downvotes on MSO represent disagreement automatically implies that the question itself is OK by some more objective standard. Note that most such comments are posted on "New Contributor" posts, not posts made by long-term users. These posts are clearly meant to educate new users as to voting culture on MSO, not to claim that the post in question is a good one.

Comment: @NicolBolas And just to be clear, I said the true of that statement doesn't matter with respect to this question.  Whether people vote in the way you claim is irrelevant to the assertion that we shouldn't mislead people into thinking they asked a good question when they didn't.  We should inform people when they ask a poor question, and not tell them it's a good question, *regardless of how people vote in this community*, and so a debate about how people vote here is *irrelevant*.  Saying something is off topic is not the same as saying you shouldn't tell the truth about it.

Comment: If you want to make the case that people posting comments saying downvotes just mean disagreement on basically every single downvoted meta question are not being interpreted by people as meaning their questions are otherwise well asked, then by all means, make such a case. That's very much on topic here. I disagree, and provided some evidence to support my position. Feel free to provide your own that contradicts it.

Comment: @animuson That's because You'd like to avoid inconvenient criticism? How should one express that they don't wan't particular change, feature or they don't agree with You opinion?
Downvotes are **mandatory**.

Comment: @Servy Wait, haven't You said that _"[...] Fading a post is in no way silencing you. It's an indication that the views are strongly opposed by the community here"_
So basically You agree, that downvotes are used properly

Comment: This is just a rant. There's no question, no suggestion, no prompting for feedback. Therefore my down vote is not because of disagreement, but because it is a _bad post_ and should be closed as off-topic since it is neither constructive nor asking for feedback.

Comment: @Skipper This isn't a post about how I think votes should be used.  Such discussion is off topic here.

Comment: @Lundin Sure there's no question, but there is a suggestion.  I'm proposing that people respond differently in their feedback to meta questions.  You're free to provide your feedback on whether you think my proposed change is a good idea to implement or a poor idea to implement, or to suggest iterations on it.  Why don't you feel that the post is a constructive proposal?  What is unconstructive about it?

Comment: @Servy As I said, it's just a long rant about certain comments you are annoyed about. It's not a request, it's not opening for a debate, it's a monologue telling people what they should do. A blog post if you will.

Comment: @BoltClock I think creating such a tag is a horrible idea, especially without any criteria about the form, contents and who may post it. Might as well name it [tag:rant]. This isn't Speaker's Corner.

Comment: @Lundin I'm putting forth a proposal for what I think other people should do (you're contridicting yourself by claiming that I'm both not requesting anyone do anything, and also telling people what to do; *tons* of proposals here on meta are telling people what the author thinks they should do, and that's certainly on topic here).  It *is* a request.  I'm more than welcome to debate the merits of the request.  If you'd care to put forth a reason for why you think my request isn't a good idea for others to do, I'd love to hear it, rather than you just saying I'm not requesting anything.

Comment: @Servy There's a whole lot of difference between "What could be done about `x`? My proposal is `y`." and "It is indisputable that `x` is a problem and you should do `y` because I say so". Dialogue vs monologue. As far as I know, you don't own the site. As for the actual topic discussed here, I am not in the slightest interested in participating, because it's a phenomenon of very little importance and I honestly don't care about it. I do care about random users making "behavior announcements" though.

Comment: @Lundin I pointed out a problem.  I've suggested what I think is my proposal for how to fix it.  I didn't say it was indisputable.  In fact, I *specifically* asked you for evidence disputing it because I'm interested to hear what you have to say on the subject.  I never claimed to own the site, but *anyone* is allowed to propose their suggestions for how people can improve it.  I don't have to own the site to make a proposal on how people should use the site.  If you don't want to participate in this proposal, then that's fine, I'm not forcing you to.

Comment: @Lundin If you think users should no longer be allowed to make proposals, then you can write your own meta post proposing that users no longer be allowed to propose changes anymore, and see how the community feels about that.  If there's wide support, then we can make proposed changes off topic here on meta.

Comment: Downvoted just to be combative.

Comment: @animuson: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193884

Comment: @Lundin: All valid concerns. I did say *maybe* we'd need a tag and didn't make one myself right away - I'm not 100% behind its creation just yet and only time will tell how its usage turns out in practice.

Comment: @BoltClock I do wonder what purpose such a tag might serve that isn't already appropriately covered by [meta-tag:discussion]. We have an announcements tag for announcements, discussion tag for discussions, and faq-proposed/faq tags for FAQ posts. This *seems* to be mostly a discussion, but like TaW it's unclear whether it's actually asking or prompting anything specific, as it's currently worded as just a rant, so I would agree with closing it as unclear. My concern re: the psa tag is that it could serve to give an artificial/inflated importance to a question that does not need or deserve it.

Comment: @TylerH What do you think is unclear about it?  I'm asking people to respond differently in comments to not state, or imply, that questions don't have quality problems when they do in fact have quality problems.  What's unclear about that?

Comment: @Servy As this website software is strictly designed in Q&A fashion, I interpret the "asking" part of guidelines here to refer to interrogative statements only. While this post may be "asking" users to change their behavior, it's in the form of a plea/rant and not an actual interrogative statement that explicitly elicits a direct response. Thus, the "unclear what you're *asking*" close reason applies, IMO, though I forgot 'til now about the "does not seek input or discussion" close reason.

Comment: @Servy I have initially refrained from CVing out of deference for the engagement from the Meta community (and to avoid any appearance of user targeting [re: our recent engagement in comments]), but after a re-read and four responses given, I think there's no need to refrain any longer (and looking at the post history I see I'm far from the first to consider the question close-worthy).

Comment: @TylerH What's your basis for asserting I'm not seeking discussion?  I've shown that I'm more than welcome to discuss the topic.  You're free to provide any input that you have on this topic.  Trying to stop people from discussing the topic is literally counter to the goal of allowing people from discussing the topic.  Posts on meta are allowed to be a proposal, and aren't required to write their proposal in the from of a grammatical question.  Lots of feature requests or proposal for policy changes aren't grammatically questions, and that's fine.

Comment: @TylerH Neither of your last two meta questions were grammatically questions.  They both simply made statements.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376162/pagination-links-when-searching-questions-by-tags-dont-honor-your-current-tags https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372401/the-thank-you-tooltip-after-flagging-a-comment-is-badly-positioned.  Are those questions "unclear" because you didn't ask a question?

Comment: @Servy Those were not tagged with [tag:discussion] but as [tag:bug] reports. It should be obvious to you what the difference is. It is really starting to seem like you're being deliberately obtuse or petulant here.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, this is a discussion.  It's not me asking a question to be answered, it's me raising a discussion, for people to discuss.  Like [this discussion of yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard) that doesn't ask a question either, and instead makes a proposal, because *making proposals is on topic on meta*.  Stating that people are allowed to propose things on meta isn't being obtuse.  Saying that people aren't allowed to write proposals for the site would be though.  It's literally one of the main reasons meta is here.

Comment: @TylerH Now if you aren't interested in discussing this issue, which is fine, you don't have to discuss every proposal that's posted on meta, then by all means, choose not to participate.  But for those that *do* want to discuss this proposal and its merits, there's no reason for you to try to stop them from providing their feedback or views on the matter.

Answer (score 22):

I cannot recall having ever seen a question asked on MSO that (explicitly or implicitly) asked us to revisit some aspect of site policy that wasn't heavily downvoted if the community was against any such changes. If [this question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8417/revisiting-our-never-guess-the-game-system-policy) had been asked on MSO, I *guarantee* it would have been downvoted to oblivion.

Similarly, when looking at a question asking about a specific question (whether it should have been closed, etc), you can pretty much always tell based on up/downvotes whether the community agrees or disagrees with the closure or whatever. If it's someone defending a question that was good, it will be upvoted; if it's a question that's bad, it will be downvoted.

[Things like this question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8714/question-marked-as-opinion-based-im-seeking-facts-and-references), where the closure was agreed to be correct by the community yet the question about it was upvoted, just don't happen on Meta Stack Overflow.

If voting patterns can clearly *predict* community agreement or disagreement... how is it unreasonable to call the present MSO voting pattern anything other than what it clearly appears to be?

Comment: I never said that users never incorporate whether or not they agree or disagree with a proposal in how they vote on a post.  I said that it's not appropriate to tell someone (or imply) that their question doesn't have any problems just because it has downvotes.  Yes, it's rather likely that a heavily downvoted question (that is making a proposal) is one where people felt that it was proposing something they don't want implemented.  But that doesn't mean the question wasn't *also* poorly researched, unclear, lacking in supporting evidence, etc.

Comment: Many of those things often go hand in hand.  If a question is unclear about what it's proposing, doesn't do a good job of explaining why its proposal is a good idea, isn't considering the ramifications of the proposal, has an offensive tone to it, etc. will result in people not supporting the underlying idea *because of how badly it was presented*.  You can fail to persuade your audience both because your underlying idea is bad, but also because *you didn't argue your position well*, even if the end result of both is failing to persuade people.

Comment: @Servy: Sure. But you haven't shown me that MSO would vote approvingly of questions that are well-written but wrong. While I've shown that *other sites* will do so. Therefore, there can be no question that agreement and disagreement are part of voting patterns on MSO.

Comment: @NicolBolas I, for one, do think it is important to point out Meta downvotes can mean disagreement when that is the most likely explanation. It's just that it quite often isn't the most likely explanation (or at least not the only likely explanation).

Comment: Why would I need to show such a thing to prove my point?  I'm not arguing that MSO doesn't incorporate disagreement with the underlying proposal into their votes (I not only think they do, but I think it's helpful).  I'm saying that just because people disagree with a proposal doesn't mean it doesn't *also* have other problems.  By all means, say you disagree with a poorly asked question you disagree with.  But don't tell the user that the question is a good question unless you really think it is well researched, clear, and all of those other things.

Comment: @Servy: But such comments are not *saying* that it is a good question. That's an implication you're reading into those comments. Furthermore, it lets the user know that, even if they did everything they could to make it a wonderful question, it would likely *still be downvoted*. This is why I don't think this pattern of behavior is helpful; it doesn't encourage users to write good questions, since good questions about things we don't want will receive downvotes.

Comment: @NicolBolas Some of them are specifically saying it's not a bad question, or *strongly* implying it.  These types of comments often result in the author *believing* that they asked a good question, even if it's not what the comment says.  We want to encourage people to propose things by *both* writing well written questions and *also* proposing things that people think are a good idea. Bad execution of a good idea isn't helpful, just as good execution of a bad idea isn't helpful.  You shouldn't be telling people to not worry about *either* type of problem with their question.

Comment: @Servy: "*You shouldn't be telling people to not worry about either type of problem with their question.*" That all depends on what kind of site you want. *You* want agreement with you; you want everyone to post the kinds of things you read and say "I like that". I don't. I want a site where people can post well-written things that I don't agree with. People who tell people that the downvotes are just disagreements are in the latter category. They're saying not to worry that people disagree with you, just keep on interacting. Because poorly written-yet-agreeable stuff gets upvoted too.

Comment: @Servy: Or to put it another way, agreement matters *more* than being good. Unless you're saying that poorly-written posts that the community agrees with don't get upvoted.

Comment: @NicolBolas Telling people (either explicitly or implicitly) not to do their research, not to think about the consequences of their proposal, not to come up with evidence of why it's a good idea, not to use a constructive tone, just because if they propose an idea people don't think is useful after doing all of that it'll be downvoted isn't useful because a big part of why you need to do all of those things is that *it makes it much more likely that people will think your proposal is useful*.

Comment: Doing your research means you won't ask ideas known to be bad, or you're iterate on them such that they address the problems presented earlier, or you'll come prepared with evidence to show why previous concerns about a proposal aren't valid, or you'll simply realize yourself that there are consequences you need to address first.  All of these things help people write proposals *that people will actually find helpful*.

Comment: @Servy: "*a big part of why you need to do all of those things is that it makes it much more likely that people will think your proposal is useful.*" Prove it. Show me a bunch of upvoted questions for which the premise of those questions drew broad disagreement. Look at the examples I showed, and show me examples of such questions on MSO. The *reality* is that this is just not how MSO works. No matter how well-researched, constructive in tone, or anything else a post is, if Meta doesn't want it to happen, it *will be downvoted*. Period, the end.

Comment: @NicolBolas You seem to think I'm proposing people change how they vote.  I'm doing no such thing.  If *you* want to propose a change...well...lots of people have, if you have something to add to the discussions not already covered, by all means, write a proposal.  All I'm saying is that we shouldn't tell people who have written really poor questions that their questions are good, and that people **only** disagree.  I'm not opposed to people saying that the community doesn't think it's a good idea, just don't say (or imply) that a bad question isn't bad while you do it.

Comment: @Servy: The problem is that, to you, a question cannot simultaneously be well-written/researched/etc ***and*** something you disagree with. By definition, if you don't agree with it, then there must be a hole in the OPs reasoning or research or whatever. In your mind, the two are one and the same.

Comment: @Servy: "*You seem to think I'm proposing people change how they vote. I'm doing no such thing.*" I know. You've made it perfectly clear that voting based on agreement is fine, valid, and healthy for the site as far as you are concerned. My point is that the result of that is that it removes the concept of disagreement-in-good-faith. That is precisely *why* those comments get written: to let the OP know that there is no such thing on this site. That no matter how much effort they put into a question, if people disagree, it will still attract downvotes.

Comment: @NicolBolas "The problem is that, to you, a question cannot simultaneously be well-written/researched/etc and something you disagree with." I never said that, and I don't think that.  In fact, I've said the opposite.  I've just said that there are plenty of questions that are both poorly asked and also inherently unhelpful ideas, and that *some* of the poor ideas are bad ideas because they're poorly researched or not clear or don't have supporting evidence.  I never said that all well written well researched questions will be considered helpful by the whole community.  I don't think that.

Comment: @NicolBolas You seemed to fail to get the point of that last quote of mine.  I was saying that your opinion that people should vote differently on meta is off topic to this discussion.  I know you think people should vote differently.  If you want to talk about it, discuss it in a question about that topic.  This is not a question about how people should vote.

Comment: @Servy: "*This is not a question about how people should vote.*" But it is. The reason people are posting the comments in question is *because of how people vote*. If they weren't voting based on disagreement, then those comments wouldn't be posted, and there would be nothing to discuss. Voting patterns are at the very core of why this question exists.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Just to play counter, I often do find myself upvoting questions about duplicate actions since more times than not, they're simple misunderstandings or civil disagreements with the action taken and not an opportunity for the OP to vent about how we're all toxic.

Comment: @NicolBolas And yet there are plenty of questions that have no proposal at all, nothing *to disagree with*, and yet people still post, "downvotes are because of disagreement" comments under the questions.  Clearly people *are* posting these comments on posts even when "disagreement" has nothing at all to do with the posts.  And this is a question on how people should comment on poorly received questions.  That depends on how people *do* vote, not on how they *should*.  This question would remain the same even if I had your views on how people *should* vote.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, not because I disagree - it's completly correct - but because it doesn't answer the question, it completly misses the point of the question. It therefore is a bad answer.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer, because it highlights the crux of the issue, which is the fact a certain vocal category of users treat MSO as an Old Boys' club and have an auto-downvote mentality for every question whose argument they don't like.

Comment: @DonQuiKong but Servy specifically said there is no question. How can this "answer" answer a "question" that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Jo well it doesn't reply to the post that is named question. Better?

Comment: @jpp Why is it helpful to lie to (or mislead) people about the quality of their question just because you don't like the criteria other people use about how they vote?  Even if you think that well written questions proposing things you think would be unhelpful is a good idea, why do you think the site is better off by telling people their questions are well written when they aren't?

Answer (score 7):

The comments that say "[Downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374994/should-we-have-a-not-an-answer-because-a-bug-was-found-label-for-questions#comment635944_374994) [on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376366/disagreement-with-downvotes-on-hold-on-specific-question#comment644838_376366) [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366818/i-go-answer-banned-because-i-answered-instead-of-commented-but-i-cannot-commen/366820#comment580193_366820) [mean](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253227/how-can-we-discourage-over-downvoting-on-questions#comment630697_253227) [disagreement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375208/bounty-should-be-awarded-to-accepted-answer-if-it-expires-failing-the-criterias#comment637446_375208)" or any such variation of those should be burninated, unless the person is explaining why they themselves have downvoted. Why? Because anything more general than saying why you yourself downvoted the question is just **mind reading**. And no offense to anyone who believes in psychic abilities, but I really really doubt that the people posting those comments can read minds.

Why is it mind reading? 2 big reasons:

1) Voting is anonymous. You don't even know who voted, much less why. Even if a person states "I downvoted because...", you can't even be sure that they really did downvote after all. So a generalized statement about why people are downvoting means that you are sure of yourself that these people who you've never met and cannot identify all downvoted for the reason you have in your head.

2) Voting can be done for any reason, or even no reason at all. Perhaps downvoter number 1 downvoted because the post was sloppily written, downvoter number 2 downvoted because it's been asked 50 times before, downvoter number 3 downvoted because they don't like your username, downvoter number 4 downvoted because they are on a small screen and misclicked, downvoter number 5 downvotes any questions that have a prime post id, downvoter number 6... see where I'm going with this? All of these claims are *exactly as accurate* as claiming that people are downvoting to express disagreement, and could only be confirmed by reading the person's mind who downvoted.

Such comments should be discouraged. I should hope that moderators will clean them up if they get flagged as "No longer needed" because they were never needed, and if a moderator would care to confirm or deny that, I'd appreciate it.

Note that I am not saying people shouldn't attempt to suggest how a post can be improved, and if a person really does feel like the post doesn't have anything wrong with it and they are just voting out of disagreement, they should feel free to express that as a comment (and should feel just as free not to, since we never want to require people to explain their downvotes). But they should be speaking for themselves, not for all downvoters, when they do so.

As Servy has said, Meta does in fact have low quality questions. I don't want to see people hiding behind "Votes are disagreement" type comments when I'm downvoting their post because they are not well researched, they are not well explained, they are confusing, they are useless, they show no effort on the part of the asker to ask a good question, or all of the above. As the tooltip says, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

---

<sub>Note that I am talking about comments that *claim* that downvotes mean disagreement. I'm still somewhat against comments that [explain that the downvotes may be because of disagreement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376980/question-deletion#comment649550_376980) because I think that still gives false hope to writers of bad questions that there isn't anything wrong, but I am not saying all those comments should be burned with fire. Before my answer gets filled with comments of people saying how "I only wanted to let the user know how Meta works," or "But people do vote that way, and the user might get discouraged when the downvotes come in," I want to make clear that I'm not talking about those kinds of comments. I'm talking about the mind reading type comments that try to speak for all the downvoters of the question. Though I might suggest next time you want to post a comment suggesting that downvotes may indicate disagreement, take a few extra seconds to read the post and consider if there is any other reason that they might be downvoted too, and suggest that as well as the disagreement reason.</sub>

Comment: "Such comments should be discouraged. I should hope that moderators will clean them up if they get flagged as "No longer needed" because they were never needed, and if a moderator would care to confirm or deny that, I'd appreciate it." I can say that these comments tend to be deleted when I flag them, but the problem is that they may not get deleted for hours or days, so the OP still sees the comment and the harm is done regardless.  Hence why I posted this question to prevent them from being posted in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, on meta or main, people vote for more specific reasons; it is usually not about agreement.

Answer (score 6):

Overall, I agree that these "downvotes can express disagreement" comments are overused and misused.  [Meta voting is complicated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918/4320665), and these comments fail to address these complexities.  You're correct that there are plenty of questions on meta that are just unclear, poorly presented, or such a common duplicate that lack of research is obvious.

But I do think that there is some inconsistency with how meta votes on discussion questions.  It's the **misapplication of downvotes on reasonable discussion questions** for users seeking, well, discussion.

For example, look at [Failed review audit on question that was edited for clarity but still closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376058/failed-review-audit-on-question-that-was-edited-for-clarity-but-still-closed).  The title is descriptive enough, it had proper tags, it described the thought process behind the review, it didn't cast blame on anyone, and it specifically asked for advice.

> Given what I can see about the question on the review audit screen, was my thought process incorrect? What should I have done better?

Yet this discussion question received 5 downvotes.  This is because the OP's thought process was in fact incorrect, as the accepted answer explains.  But what is objectively downvoteable about the question?  Let's explore some typical downvote reasons:

- Unclear/unhelpful?  It's not unclear.  The post has a link to the audit, a description of the actions taken, an explanation of the thought process behind the review, and a direct question about the validity of the thought process.  There isn't any distracting rants or irrelevant information.
- Lack of research effort?  There isn't an obvious duplicate, and no one even offered a potential duplicate.  And since this question is about the nuances of a specific audit review, it's not like there was previous advice for the OP to find about it.
- Disagreement with the feature proposed?  This isn't a feature request, and it wasn't mistagged.  The question specifically asked whether the OP's analysis of the audit was flawed.
- Meta Specific reasons? It's not a "Trojan Horse" because there isn't a hidden feature request.  Nor is the underlying assertion "I failed the audit and I don't understand why" anything that people can really disagree with.  It doesn't overstate things superlatively.  It's not a bandwagon post.

And of course, the obligatory ["why was my meta question downvoted" comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376058/failed-review-audit-on-question-that-was-edited-for-clarity-but-still-closed#comment643086_376060) and the [hand-washing explanation comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376058/failed-review-audit-on-question-that-was-edited-for-clarity-but-still-closed#comment643089_376060) for the (IMO unwarranted) downvotes.

Situations like this, where the question asker provides good background information, isn't neglecting research, and asks for a reasonable discussion without ranting should not be downvoted.  The comments "downvotes can express disagreement" are acceptable in cases like this.

Comment: A good example. You still show agreement/disagreement... by voting on the answer(s), not on the question. An answer stating "yes your thought process is wrong, here's why" that gets a pile of upvotes sends a very clear instruction. A dozen downvotes on the very honest question ... not so much.

Comment: This is not a question about how people should vote.  If you want to propose people vote differently, there are plenty of questions that *are* about that topic.  But *this* meta question is about informing people when their question has problems with how they ask it, or at least not indicating that a question *doesn't* have such problems when it really does.

Comment: @Servy I'm disagreeing with your question's premise that the problem is mainly with the existence/misuse of such comments.  I think the legitimate use cases/origins of such comments are relevant to the discussion of not misusing them.

Comment: @ryanyuyu But I described that exact use case right in the question, and said that if you really feel that there aren't any problems with *how* the question is asked, just what it's proposing, then I encouraged people to say that's their opinion.  You're not disagreeing with me, you're just repeating the last paragraph of the question.  At least, for the bits of the answer that are actually on topic.

Comment: @Servy your final paragraphs all mention disagreements with a potentially bad _proposal_ (feature-request).  I'm saying you are overlooking these comments existing on _discussion_ questions so I'm broadening your advice.  And specifically, I don't think your question (as lengthy as it already is) gives enough attention to the legitimate use cases of such comments.  We do _mostly_ agree, but I think your post is missing a bit of nuance I that felt is important.

Comment: @Servy That being said, I'd be fine with deleting this answer if I can edit your question to better incorporate my concerns.  My edits would be extensive though.

Comment: @ryanyuyu People propose things outside of feature requests.  I said proposals for a reason.  If I meant feature requests, I'd have said feature requests.  Given that you're talking about proposals in questions that aren't feature requests, that'd be consistent with my statement.

Comment: @ryanyuyu What concerns do you have that aren't addressed in the question?  The only thing I've noticed on several readings is your discussion on how people should vote, which I specifically avoided because it's off topic to the discussion I'm trying to have.

Comment: A few months ago, in the comments to one of those strangely downvoted Meta questions you speak of, a fellow Meta denizen suggested that some folks downvote genuine, advice-seeking questions as if it were a way to answer "No". I find that perplexing enough to be worthy of a Meta question (and I have been procrastinating the writing of that question ever since).

Answer (score -15):

In [Clarify that opinion voting on meta is the norm rather than exception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371095/clarify-that-opinion-voting-on-meta-is-the-norm-rather-than-exception), I showed that "quality voting" and "agreement voting" are equivalent for Meta purposes.

So it doesn't really matter which of them a user has in mind when casting a vote.

Comment: And that linked question (+ answer) has been downvoted enough for us to understand that we should not be relying on any of it: either it's low quality and not well founded; or people generally disagree with it. Either way, it's no good.

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming This is not a deterrent from posting links to it though. I've yet to receive a compelling argument against it, so the more times I post it, the more likely it is that I'll receive any hint of what could possibly be wrong with it eventually.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev [Okay, let me give it a go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377301/2751851).