# I am looking for the "experience" filter to search for positions

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Experience (Fresher, Mid-level, Senior) filter under job portal was there under job filters in the previous version of Stack Overflow, It was very helpful for users like me who only want to apply for fresher position.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this.  I haven't used Jobs, so my only guess is the filter is either still there and they expect you to find it, or there was some prominent announcement that it's been removed, and they expect you to know that.  I think both are bad reasons to downvote.  Anyway, I hope you find what you need.

Comment: It's still there, under "Background".

Comment: @DanBron probably because the FR tag.

Comment: This question actually proofs @Servy point in his post on ['Meta does in fact have low quality questions'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377208/meta-does-in-fact-have-low-quality-questions).. @ Dan Bron I believe it got so many downvotes because it shows literally no research effort..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image should answer your question, now you even have the option to define a lower and upper threshold with the following choices to pick from:

- Student
- Junior
- Mid-Level
- Senior
- Lead
- Manager

[image]