# Do down votes affect anything on meta?

Tags: support, downvotes, meta, post-ban

Down votes can give you a post ban on the main site, which is understandable. But here at meta, especially when someone is suggesting something, votes usually indicates if the user agrees or not, and not if the question shows research effort and is useful and clear, or if the answer is useful.

So my question is, does down votes have the same effect here at meta as it has on the main site?

Comment: Downvotes on meta can also indicate that the question does not show research effort/is not useful. It doesn't necessarily just mean people don't agree. I guess that's not the main point of your question though.

Comment: Related reading to what @Don't Panic commented: [Meta does in fact have low quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377208/7795130)

Comment: not so much affect on the user account, but they do tend to be misunderstood equally badly on both sites, with the same level of frustration as a result. Downvotes on a meta post about downvotes are a special category of hopeless.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you can get answer-banned in the same fashion as you would on the main site on Meta.

However, you have to post *consistently* poorly received answers to trip the *very, very* relaxed limits here.

So yeah, it can happen.  But you have to *really* work for it.

Other than that, since there is no reputation on Meta, you cannot lose reputation for downvotes (but you *can* lose tag points, just like you would on the main site).

Comment: Actually, question bans are specifically *disabled* on Meta. Answer bans are still in effect but in practice no one ever hits the tresholds

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  That's good to know.  I've revised my answer.  Makes sense since I've never seen anyone trip either ban here anyway...

Comment: I can’t even find users that received answer quality warnings, let alone bans...

Comment: FTR, I searched for explicit confirmation and found it [used to be enabled but very hard to hit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/140890). However, as a moderator, looking at the question ban status area of a given meta account now shows *disabled*.

Comment: In B4 secret badge, "Persistent: Answer Banned On Meta"

Comment: Wheee, by pure coincidence I stumbled upon [confirmation that per-site Metas have no question bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222825/140890) (relevant info there added by animuson).